# How to make environments appear by using code abbreviations?

Tags: environments, shortcut

I am looking for a way in LaTeX to make environments like `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` appear by just typing in a self-made abbreviation, e.g. 'be'. For the reason that the abbreviation shall not be a command, I do not want to do this with `\newcommand`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is **not** a good idea to do this. It makes the code very hard to read and plus it is not possible with certain envs as they look explicitly for `\end{env}`. It is much better to use you editor to insert envs for you. Some editors even provide features to insert entire subtemplates.

Comment: most editors will let you enter `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` in two or three keystrokes but the details depend on the editor, you have not said which you are using

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am using TeXmaker on Mac.

Comment: Do you never need to type any words which include a 'b' followed by an 'e'?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to 'reinvent the wheel' here. Texmaker has Alt+Shift+M to insert a displayed equation environment, Ctrl+Shift+M for inline maths, Ctrl+Shift+L/R for left/right delimiters, and there are a few others. There's a list in the manual.

And then see section 4.4 of the manual for environments for which shortcuts have not already been defined.

You could assign a user tag to a Shift+F1 to Shift+F10 key. For example, you could define a repeated align environment thus using the tag %align and assigning it to Shift+F1:

```
\begin{align}
   &=     \nonumber\\
  &= 
\end{align}
```